# Dependencies between twitter gem, adressable and rdf-sesame

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, rubygems, sesame

The dependencies between adressable and rdf-sesame is fix but twitter needs a newer version. Someone got an idea how to solve the dependencies between those ? ( Have an Sesame repository and want to query data to compare with tweets)

```
################################################
## RDF components and libraries
################################################
gem 'rdf', '~> 0.3.11.1'
gem 'addressable', '~> 2.2.8'
gem 'rdf-sesame'
gem 'sparql-client', '~> 0.0.9'

gem 'twitter'

Fetching additional metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "addressable":
  In Gemfile:
    dacodi_adapters (>= 0) ruby depends on
      twitter (~> 5.11.0) ruby depends on
        addressable (~> 2.3) ruby

    addressable (2.2.8)
```

Comment: We just changed the dependencies to the newest rdf gem version and it seems to be working...

Comment: if you have found a solution yourself, could you post it here as answer? Answering your own questions is fine, even encouraged, as your solution may help others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our case we just created a new gem of sesame with other dependencies (because the sesame connector just solves the REST connection to the sesame repository and the insertion of statement by statement works fine for us). For querying we use the sparql-client.

So we created our owen gem and changed the information in the rdf-sesame-0.3.0.gemspec file:

```
s.files = Dir.glob('lib/**/*.rb')

  s.installed_by_version = "2.2.2" if s.respond_to? :installed_by_version

  if s.respond_to? :specification_version then
    s.specification_version = 3

    if Gem::Version.new(Gem::VERSION) >= Gem::Version.new('1.2.0') then
      s.add_runtime_dependency(%q<json_pure>, [">= 1.4.2"])
      s.add_runtime_dependency(%q<rdf>, ["~> 1.1.6"])
      s.add_development_dependency(%q<yard>, [">= 0.6.0"])
      s.add_development_dependency(%q<rspec>, [">= 2.1.0"])
      s.add_development_dependency(%q<rdf-spec>, ["~> 0.3.0"])
    else
      s.add_dependency(%q<json_pure>, [">= 1.4.2"])
      s.add_dependency(%q<rdf>, ["~> 1.1.6"])
      s.add_dependency(%q<yard>, [">= 0.6.0"])
      s.add_dependency(%q<rspec>, [">= 2.1.0"])
      s.add_dependency(%q<rdf-spec>, ["~> 0.3.0"])
    end
  else
    s.add_dependency(%q<json_pure>, [">= 1.4.2"])
    s.add_dependency(%q<rdf>, ["~> 1.1.6"])
    s.add_dependency(%q<yard>, [">= 0.6.0"])
    s.add_dependency(%q<rspec>, [">= 2.1.0"])
    s.add_dependency(%q<rdf-spec>, ["~> 0.3.0"])
  end
end
```

EDIT: The developers of the gem just released rdf-sesame v1.1.0 on rubygems where the issue has been solved. :) [ruby-rdf/rdf-sesame](https://github.com/ruby-rdf/rdf-sesame)